# Why is std::atan2 returning -0.0?

Tags: c++, mathematics

Really? Negative zero?!

```
double Vector2D::GetFacingAngle(const Vector2D& target, const Vector2D& source) {
    a2de::Vector2D facingVec(Vector2D(source) - Vector2D(target));

    //Negating 'y' argument to account for flipped nature of 'y' screen coordinates.
    double result = std::atan2(-facingVec.GetY(), facingVec.GetX());

    //Which causes -0.0 as a possible result when source is right of target at the same 'y' coordinate.
    if(a2de::Math::IsEqual(result, -0.0)) return 0.0;
    return result;
}
```

Is this a common behavior? (Similar to subtracting 'y' coordinates for 'up' movement in screen coordinates contrary to Cartesian coordinates.)

Comment: BTW, you shouldn't need to care whether it comes out negative zero or positive zero.  Any further floating point math you do on the result should work correctly anyway.

Comment: It doesn't matter at all, [because `-0.0 == 0.0` according to IEEE 754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_zero#Comparisons)

Comment: @MaikSemder From an aesthetic standpoint it does (like...displaying the angle to the screen)

Comment: @Casey I see, no reason to touch the math code though. The math code works fine. This is a GUI problem. Make the values *user friendly* in the UI code before you show it on screen, rather than polluting the basic math code with unnecessary comparisons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're seeing is a [signed zero](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_zero), which is a possibility in certain systems of number representation, including the IEEE standard used for C++ floating point representation, even though it isn't really a thing in "ordinary" mathematics.

The link contains some notes on behavior and handling of the occurrence, although beyond that it's not entirely clear to me what you're asking, specifically -- it's not a bug with `atan2` though. In fact, [the wiki article on the function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2) notes that the relevant Intel assembly instruction (`FPATAN`), which you're likely generating here, will produce a negative zero when first parameter in negative zero but the second is positive zero. Your explicit negation of your vector's Y component could easily produce such a scenario.